# How to send zip file in a response to UI client

Tags: java, rest

I have a list of zip files in a directory and I want to send a zip file as per the file name received in the request, in the response, how can we do it.
Zip file is already present inside directory, just need to send in response

Comment: What exactly is a problem with that? Endpoint configuration, getting the actual file, etc...?

Comment: actually the issue is i have a logging zip file present in my directory. so on the api call i have to return that file in the response, i checked other answers for this query it gives creating new zip file and sending it but for me i already have zip, all i need to do is send it

Comment: you just need to return a file for request so pretty basic stuff. look at it here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file it should work for every file

Comment: got it working, thank you...